# Outputting a Scalding TypedPipe to a SequenceFile in multiple directories based on one of the fields

Tags: hadoop, cascading, scalding, sequencefile

I'm using Scalding on Hadoop, I have a large dataset in the form of a TypedPipe I wish to output in chunks based on one of the data fields.

For example the data is `<category, field1, field2>`, and I want the data for each category stored in a SequenceFile in a separate category, e.g. `outPath/cat1`, `outPath/cat2` etc. And I want a single MapReduce phase (or avoid loops).

I have read about the `TemplatedTsv` option here:
[How to bucket outputs in Scalding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357987/how-to-bucket-outputs-in-scalding)

And here:
[How to output data with Hive-style directory structure in Scalding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28687539/how-to-output-data-with-hive-style-directory-structure-in-scalding)

However this works only if you want a Tsv file, not a SequenceFile.

Obviously a loop works:

```
var category = 0L

for (category <- categories) {
    data
    .filter(_.category == category)
    .map(t => (NullWritable.get, new BytesWritable(SerializationUtils.serialize(t))))
    .write(WritableSequenceFile(outPath + "/" + category))
}
```

So is there an equivalent way to `TemplateTsv` which would work with writing a SequenceFile, avoiding a loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [com.twitter.scalding.TemplatedSequenceFile](http://twitter.github.io/scalding/index.html#com.twitter.scalding.TemplatedSequenceFile) which may do what you need. It looks just like TemplateTsv but with output to SequenceFile